# Sort and Join two tables by date

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have the following tables:

```
posts
post_id | text    | posts_date
1       | blabla  | 06-06-2013
2       | bababa  | 09-06-2013
...
```

and

```
comments
comment_id | post_id | user_id | text            | comments_date
1          | 1       | 55      | I like this...  | 06-08-2013
2          | 1       | 66      | Yeah, me also!  | 06-07-2013
3          | 2       | 55      | I like this...  | 06-10-2013
4          | 2       | 66      | Yeah, me also!  | 06-11-2013
...
```

I need a sql statement that returns all columns from both tables and orders them first by posts_date and then by the comments_date for this post.

So the resulting table from the query should be

```
post_id | text    | posts_date  |  comment_id  | user_id | text            | comments_date
1       | blabla  | 06-06-2013  |   2          | 66      | Yeah, me also!  | 06-07-2013
1       | blabla  | 06-06-2013  |   1          | 55      | I like this...  | 06-08-2013
2       | bababa  | 09-06-2013  |   3          | 55      | I like this...  | 06-10-2013
2       | bababa  | 09-06-2013  |   4          | 66      | Yeah, me also!  | 06-11-2013
```

I thought of something like

```
SELECT * FROM comments c, (SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY posts_date ASC) p WHERE p.post_id = c.post_id ORDER BY comments_date ASC
```

but that didn't seem to give the right results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM COMMENTS C JOIN POSTS P ON C.post_id = P.post_id 
ORDER BY P.posts_date,C.comments_date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * From Posts
inner join Comments on Posts.Post_id = Comments.Post_ID
order by posts.Post_date, comments.comment_date
```

will give you only posts with comments.

If you want posts even if they don't have any comments then

```
Select * From Posts
left join Comments on Posts.Post_id = Comments.Post_ID
order by posts.Post_date, comments.comment_date
```

Learn joins mate, can't leave home without them.